# css: плавное "выдвигание" созданного блока

Tags: reactjs, css3, css-animation, transition

подскажите, можно ли как-то реализовать плавное "выдвигание" `<div />` блока (т.е. появление с 0 высоты до исходной высоты под каким-то другим блоком), если блок не присутствует изначально в DOM, а в какой-то момент создаётся динамически?

я реализовал это через "костыль" -

- блок уже изначально создан, но его высота 0px (скрыт)
- при наведении на карточку блоку выставляется нужный размер

недостатки такого подхода - приходится вручную устанавливать высоту блока (а этой информации у меня изначально нет), приходится отрисовывать блок всегда, а не когда он нужен

```css
.main {
  width:              200px;
  
  border:             1px solid black;
}

.title {
  height:             100px;
  line-height:        100px;
  text-align:         center;
}

.main .animated {
  border-top:         1px solid black;

  background:         #ffff80;

  text-align:         center;

  height:             0px;
  line-height:        0px;
  overflow:           hidden;

  transition:         all 0.75s;
}

.main:hover .animated {
  height:             45px;
  line-height:        45px;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='title'>Наведи на меня</div>
  <div class='animated'>Выдвигаемый блок</div>
</div>
```

это нужно для элемента `Card` от Ant Design, в котором при наведении должна плавно появиться (отъехать) плашка `actions`

когда наводится мышка на карточку, то появляется блок 'actions' - `.ant-card-actions` и вот ее отъезд и хотелось бы реализовать

Вот код этой карточки и эффекта:

https://codesandbox.io/s/support-more-content-configuration-antd-5-3-2-forked-ycqsp9?file=/demo.tsx

Код (а то песочница тяжелая):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import {
  EditOutlined,
  EllipsisOutlined,
  SettingOutlined
} from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Avatar, Card } from "antd";

const { Meta } = Card;

const App: React.FC = () => {
  // показывать или скрывать блок с кнопками
  // ПРОБЛЕМА: НУЖНО ЗАСТАВИТЬ БЛОК НЕ ПРОСТО ПОЯВЛЯТЬСЯ МГНОВЕННО (ОН СОЗДАЕТСЯ ДИНАМИЧЕСКИ), 
  // А ПЛАВНО ВЫЕЗЖАТЬ СВЕРХНУ ВНИЗ
  const [isToolbarEnabled, setToolbar] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <Card
      onMouseEnter={() => setToolbar(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setToolbar(false)}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      cover={
        <img
          alt="example"
          src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png"
        />
      }
      actions={/* указывается блок, который будет отрисован снизу элемента */
        isToolbarEnabled
          ? [
              <SettingOutlined key="setting" />,
              <EditOutlined key="edit" />,
              <EllipsisOutlined key="ellipsis" />
            ]
          : undefined
      }
    >
      <Meta
        avatar={<Avatar src="https://joesch.moe/api/v1/random" />}
        title="Card title"
        description="This is the description"
      />
    </Card>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Плавное появление элемента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1273957/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Если создаваемый блок не превышает высоты родительского, то задача решается просто. Какая максимальная высота может быть у `.animated`? Больше чем у `.main`? И ещё нюанс - `.main` имеет сплошной непрозрачный фон?

Comment: @MrP, нет, не дубликат, добавил в вопросе уточнение что должно быть

Comment: @UModeL, добавил в вопрос код в котором показал что где именно хотел бы плавность выплывания (если это возможно вообще) - https://codesandbox.io/s/support-more-content-configuration-antd-5-3-2-forked-ycqsp9?file=/demo.tsx - у блока `<ul class='ant-card-actions'>...</ul>`, который появляется когда навожу мышку на карточку

Comment: @Zhihar: при переходе по ссылке - 100% загрузка ЦП и краш страницы :(

Comment: @UModeL - да, песочница тяжелая у них похоже, у меня тоже появилось "Oops", но повторно зайдя загрузилось - я на всякий случай еще и сам код добавил в вопрос чтоб понятно было

Answer (score 2):

Вы это имели ввиду? Что высота разная для .animation?

```css
.main {
  width:              200px;
  
  border:             1px solid black;
}

.title {
  height:             100px;
  line-height:        100px;
  text-align:         center;
}

.main .animated {
  border-top:         1px solid black;

  background:         #ffff80;

  text-align:         center;

  height:             0px;
  line-height:        0px;
  overflow:           hidden;

  transition:         all 0.75s;
}

.main:hover .animated {
  height:             100%;
  line-height:        45px;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='title'>Наведи на меня</div>
  <div class='animated'>Выдвигаемый блок</div>
</div>

<div class='main'>
  <div class='title'>Наведи на меня</div>
  <div class='animated'>Выдвигаемый блок Выдвигаемый блок</div>
</div>

<div class='main'>
  <div class='title'>Наведи на меня</div>
  <div class='animated'>Выдвигаемый блок Выдвигаемый блок Выдвигаемый блок</div>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем - я в вопросе добавил код (https://codesandbox.io/s/support-more-content-configuration-antd-5-3-2-forked-ycqsp9?file=/demo.tsx) - когда мышка наводится на карточку, то появляется снизу плашка с кнопками (блок `<ul class='ant-card-actions'>...</ul>`) - вот и хочется, чтоб эта плашка аккуратно выплывала, а не появлялась мгновенно

Comment: @Zhihar вы всё перечислили, но не назвали самого главного, что сайт на React )). Там же другой подход анимации.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи: абсолютно верно. Тоже это хотел отписать.

Comment: А я подумал, что они просто добавляют в DOM модель элемент, а дальше работают все те же правила

Comment: @Zhihar сразу видно не вы писали сайт)

Comment: какой именно? почему? :)